# Writing json response to a recordset in MS Access VBA

Tags: json, vba, ms-access, ado, dao

I have a Json response from an API that returns a list of customers from the database I am querying.

I need to display these customers (usually 4-5 customers, outlier could be 50) on a form for the user to select which one to save to the local database.

This is the second API I am using, so i already have a table with
Firstname
Lastname
Address
Suburb

My previous API was a SQL query so I just created a DAO recordset and then set the .recordset of the form.

If I have a loop of patient details to record.. how can i put this into a recordset (DAO or ADO) and then
use this to fill the form?

The other option is just SQL update a local TEMP table.. which is fine but I wanted to know if there was a 'virtual list' way I can build this recordset?
(And would this even be a good idea?)

Comment: this [vba json parser](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) will most likely help. you can place the JSON into a dictionary, then loop the dictionary and write into a recordset.

Comment: @Scott thanks, i know how to loop, the question is how do I create a record set with no table or query? Ado?

Comment: `CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")` will create a recordset.  Eg. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60695298/passing-a-multidimensional-array-into-a-recordset-variable-in-vba/60698255#60698255